# Resolve network connection problem at startup

Tags: networking, internet, network-manager

I encounter problems during starting up Ubuntu 12.04 laptop. There is no internet connection (wired network connection is established though) and there is no error message from network manager or other system part.

In the very beginning, email is working but after 2-3 min it is not working anymore.

Other pcs are working (email & internet) without problem. Router shows that internet connection is alive.

After resetting router (and network connection as well), problem disappears till next boot.

Which error or log file should I look in to try resolving the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the output of 'ifconfig' as soon as you boot and after the connection is dropped? Also, can execute 'route', see the IP of your default gateway, and try to ping it? For example:

```
jmhal@pluto:~$ ifconfig
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 00:22:43:44:a2:d3  
      inet end.: 192.168.0.2  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Masc:255.255.255.0
      endereço inet6: fe80::222:43ff:fe44:a2d3/64 Escopo:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
      pacotes RX:336542 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 quadro:0
      Pacotes TX:169868 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 portadora:0
      colisões:0 txqueuelen:1000 
jmhal@pluto:~$ route
Tabela de Roteamento IP do Kernel
Destino         Roteador        MáscaraGen.    Opções Métrica Ref   Uso Iface 
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 wlan0
jmhal@pluto:~$ ping 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=52.1 ms
```

This way you'll be sure if the connection to the router is up or not.

Comment: Is this an answer or a question??

Comment: Both. Either or...

Comment: Thank you jmhal, I just wait to see it happening once more, it is not in every boot. However I would like as well to search in the right log file to find the cause